# sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError:database is locked

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

Can anybody help me to solve this error !!

I was making a web app using `flask (python)`. After completing the project ,I was able to login only with user which has register newly not with user which has registered before him.!!

so I thought it was due to the `overflow` in database(lack of knowledge)
,to solve I executed this command`( d b . drop _ all() )` in my terminal

after which my database get locked  , and I am getting this error while registration only!!

Comment: by executing db.session.rollback() my error got solved!!

Comment: If you are able to resolve your problem then you may post your own answer on it